# ComboBox not showing bound values

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have a comboBox `cb` and an `ObservableList<StringProperty> data`
I have bound the `cb`'s `Items` to `data` as follows:

```
Bindings.bindContent(cb.getItems(), data);
```

Suppose `data` has the following items: `str1, str2, str3, str4`

When I change `data`, the combobox gets the new list without any problem.
But if `str3` is selected in `cb` and I change the value of `str3` to `NewStr3` in data, that change is not getting displayed in cb. And sometimes the list displayed is also wrong (it shows str3 instead of NewStr3) eventhough underlying data it refers is correct.

How can I force combobox to display new values when the underlying model is changed?

Comment: selection behaviour isn't entirely intuitive and buggy: the clear-on-set is intentional as of rejection of https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-19820 (though uncommented, @James_D got it quite right, IMO), behaviour-on-update is buggy https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-38394. The not always displaying the change in the popup sounds like a spurious bug: https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-29709 is closed as cannotreproduce - would be cool if you have an example that demonstrates the misbehaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selected item in a combo box is not required to be an element of the combo box's items list. (For example, in an editable combo box, you can type in an item which is not in the list.) If you think about your example from this perspective, it's no surprise that it behaves as you describe.

If you want to force the selected value to be an element of the underlying list when that list may change, you need to define how the selected item should change if the list changes in a way in which it no longer contains the selected item (it is not obvious how you will do this, and probably depends on your application logic). Once you know what you want to do, you can implement it with a `ListChangeListener`:

```
cb.getItems().addListener((ListChangeListener.Change change) -> {
    String newSelectedItem = ... ; // figure item that should be selected instead
    cb.setValue(newSelectedItem);
});
```

The simplest implementation would be just `cb.setValue(null);`, which would mean no item was selected if the list changed so that it no longer contained the currently selected item.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I didn't even have to write this listener. Just added and removed a dummy object from the list, and it automatically picked up the changes. You might edit your answer to include this. Accepted your answer as it pointed me in right direction

Comment: @sinu in an ideal world, you would implement a custom selectionModel that encapsulates whatever you need - unfortunately, the implementation of selection behaviour is smeared across choicebox, its skin and choiceboxSelectionModel, requires a complete re-write (like ChoiceBoxX in my git, which is intended as a POC of the advantages of a clear separation of responsibilities)

Answer (score -1):

Oops ... mis-read the comboBox for a choiceBox - while the basics of this answer apply to both combo- and choiceBox, I don't have a custom ComboBoxX - yet :-)

Basically, it's the responsibility of the SelectionModel to update itself on changes to the items. The intended behaviour implemented in core is to completely clear the selection - that is, null the selectedItem and set selectedIndex to -1 - if the old item was the selectedItem and is replaced or removed. The typical solution for custom behaviour is to implement a custom selection model and set it:

```
/**
 * A SelectionModel that updates the selectedItem if it is contained in
 * the data list and was replaced/updated.
 * 
 * @author Jeanette Winzenburg, Berlin
 */
public static class MySelectionModel<T> extends ChoiceBoxSelectionModel<T> {

    public MySelectionModel(ChoiceBoxX<T> cb) {
        super(cb);
    }

    @Override
    protected void itemsChanged(Change<? extends T> c) {
        // selection is in list
        if (getSelectedIndex() != -1) {
            while (c.next()) {
                if (c.wasReplaced() || c.wasUpdated()) {
                    if (getSelectedIndex() >= c.getFrom()
                            && getSelectedIndex() < c.getTo()) {
                        setSelectedItem(getModelItem(getSelectedIndex()));
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // super expects a clean change
        c.reset();
        super.itemsChanged(c);
    }
 }

 // usage
 myChoiceBox.setSelectionModel(new MySelectionModel(myChoiceBox));
```

Unfortunately, core choiceBox doesn't play by the rule - it severely interferes with model's responsibilities (probably because the model implementation doesn't stand up to its duties) which requires a complete re-write of the whole collaborator-stack (choiceBox, -skin, copied -behaviour) such as [ChoiceBoxX](https://github.com/kleopatra/swingempire-fx/tree/master/fx8-swingempire/src/java/de/swingempire/fx/scene/control/choiceboxx) - which I did just to learn a bit, try remove some of its smells and fix some bugs.